# Passing int via winsocks send

Tags: c++

How could it be possible to send int (not using third party libraries) via windows sockets Send: 
it requires (const char *) as parameter.

My attempt was to send int like this:

```
unsigned char * serialize_int(unsigned char *buffer, int value)
{
  /* Write big-endian int value into buffer; assumes 32-bit int and 8-bit char. */
  buffer[0] = value >> 24;
  buffer[1] = value >> 16;
  buffer[2] = value >> 8;
  buffer[3] = value;
  return buffer + 4;
}
```

but Send() wants (const char *). I'm stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is easily fixed. The compiler wants a `char*` (ignore `const` for now), but you're passing an `unsigned char*`, and the only real difference is how the compiler interprets each byte when manipulated. Therefore you can easily cast the pointer from `unsigned char*` to `char*`. This way:

```
(char*)serialize_int(...)
```

Comment: Really it helped! Just added self-confidence:)

on the server side it looks like:
   unsigned char array[4] = {PerIoData->Buffer[0], PerIoData->Buffer[1], PerIoData->Buffer[2], PerIoData->Buffer[3]};
   
   unsigned int out = ((array[0]<<24)|(array[1]<<16)|(array[2]<<8)|(array[3]));

Answer (score 1):

```
const int networkOrder = htonl(value);

const result = send(socket, reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&networkOrder), sizeof(networkOrder), 0);
```